# How to Disable root account Direct Login after adding a password?

Tags: root

I was trying to use `sudo` to change the default account name, but it didn't work. So, I added a password to the root account and logged in as root. By default, you can't login to root through the login screen, adding a password to it allowed this.

It worked, but I have found another problem; I can't figure out how to remove the password again. Several guides online say you can do it, but don't say how.

Comment: I'm sure this question or a variant of it has been asked here before...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disable remote login**

Run `sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

and set `PermitRootLogin yes` to 'no'.

Reboot or restart the ssh service with `/etc/init.d/ssh restart`

**Disable root completely**

To completely disable root-access, either lock it via `passwd --lock root` or remove the password by executing `passwd -d root`

Comment: This only prevents logins via SSH not directly from the keyboard.

Comment: Don't know about older versions but I just found out that Raspbian 9 has `pam_unix.so nullok_secure` by default, so `passwd -d [user]` will allow login without a password. `passwd -l [user]` _must_ be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that `sudo passwd -l root` does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: `passwd -l` is short for `passwd --lock` :D

Comment: I used your command to disable root login into the GUI, but I still get prompted for a login, only now root does not work any more and the standard user "pi" is also not logging in - albeit not stating an error, simply showing a login promt again.

Comment: Did you actually use `passwd -l` with no username/account ? **REMEMBER:** never use code from the internet without understanding what it does.